# open a text file through cmd.exe in .net

Tags: .net

I want to open one notepad file by using command prompt.I wrote this codes

```
  Process proc = new Process();
  ProcessStartInfo ps = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe");
  ps.Arguments = "notepad E:\\Zlabel.txt";
  proc.StartInfo = ps;
  proc.Start();
```

But i am not getting the desired result. It is just opening cmd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use: `Process.Start("E:\\Zlabel.txt");`

It should work ok. The file will be opened in the default viewer for the txt extension.

**For Printing**

You might use the [Print](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772773%28WS.10%29.aspx) command.

```
Process.Start("print E:\\Zlabel.txt")
```

Comment: @Nagendra: I'm confused. Adrian gave the answer you asked for, to open a file using Notepad, but now you are saying you need instead to print the file? Could you please clarify?

Comment: the answer is working fine.But i want to print one txt file from cmd.But it is not taking.even this "notepad E:\\Zlabel.txt" is not working why?